# What can we learn from the sign structure of the Jacobian matrix?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I am studying a $4 \times 4$ Jacobian matrix. I know the sign structure (that is, I know whether each element is positive, negative or zero), but I do not know magnitudes of each elements (i.e. their numerical size).
\begin{align}
  J = \begin{bmatrix}
    - & 0 & - &  +   \\[0.3em]
    + & + & - &  +  \\[0.3em]
    - & 0 & + &  +  \\[0.3em]
    0 & + & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

I want to know what I can learn from the sign structure. For example, I know it is a saddle for a numerical example with the same structure.

Please offer pointers or directions to look in, especially regards stability analysis.

Comment: This [paper pp. 288-289](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/maini/PKM%20publications/387.pdf) is an example where sign structures are discussed. I want something much more general. I'm not necessarily interested in Turing instability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the [Routh-Hurwitz stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion), which is closely related to the [eponymous theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Routh-HurwitzTheorem.html). Basically, this relates the sign of subdeterminants of the matrix to the sign of the real parts of the eigenvalues of the original matrix -- which is quite relevant for stability analysis. For your specific structure, especially given the fact that quite a few entries are zero, you might get quite far using this approach.